# I keep getting KeyError: 0, what seems to be the problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, k-means

```
def get_new_centroid(clustered_points, k_centroids):
    clusters = [] #dictionary to hold clusters with new centroids
    for i in range(k_centroids):
        new_centroid = compute_new_centroid(clustered_points[i])#compute for new centroids for n centroids
        temp = new_centroid, clustered_points[i] #return an array of tuples with new centroids and clustered points
        clusters.append(temp)
    return clusters

def compute_new_centroid(elem):
    new_centroid = []
    for i in range(2):
        total = 0
        for j in range(len(elem)):
            total = total + elem[j][i] #compute for new centroids
        total = total / len(elem) #compute for new centroids
        new_centroid.append(total)
    return new_centroid
```

Here is the code snippet, I keep getting error at

`"new_centroid = compute_new_centroid(clustered_points[i])"`

I tried checking if it's about the assignment but it's not

Comment: please check if `clustered_points` is empty or not?

Comment: i tried using conditional statements to check if its empty or not, i still keep getting the same error so I think it's not empty

Comment: This `KeyError` happens when you try to access a key that does not exist in a dictionary. Try to check if the key exists first (using `if i in clustered_points`)

Answer (score -1):

KeyError occurs when there is no key in clustered_points that matches the value in i. Perhaps you could print all the items in clustered_points to check against the range of values i may have ?

Comment: Why is my answer getting  -1  !?
If the OP simply printed the clustered_points variable, the KeyError would become apparent and easy to spot. That would have solved the problem right there!